# Quarkus Amazon Lambda extension and testing multiple handlers

Tags: quarkus

I have a Quarkus project with a few different Lambda handlers.

In order to 'deploy' or 'select' the handler to use, the documentation states that we should set the `quarkus.lambda.handler` application.properties setting, or `QUARKUS_LAMBDA_HANDLER` environment variable accordingly.

E.g.

```
quarkus.lambda.handler=my-handler
```

The handler is named with the `@Named` annotation. E.g.

```
@Named("my-handler")
```

The application.properties setting or environment variable works for selecting a single handler for testing purposes, but I run into trouble when trying to test multiple handlers in one go in the project.

I've tried using a System property to set `quarkus.lambda.handler` in the hopes that it would override the setting, and also tried modifying the live JVM system environment variables using my test setup method (`@BeforeAll`), however I think that the test run caches environment variables at the start, and so modifying things during a test session doesn't work.

Is there a known or valid way to test multiple quarkus lambda function handlers in a project without having to edit the application.properties file each time I want to test a different handler?

Comment: did you solve this please? If yes, how?

Comment: Sorry @scarface, unfortunately I did not. Maybe the way to go here is to invoke each test one at a time (instead of the whole suite of tests), each time changing the `quarkus.lambda.handler` environment variable to the appropriate lambda handler under test.

Comment: Thanks @Shogan. How I approached it in the end was that I injected the instance of the class representing the Lambda handler and called `handleRequest` method with the input that I wanted and I asserted what I wanted (output, invocations of AWS API,...).

Comment: Ahh, nice one @scarface. Thanks for letting me know. Glad you arrived at some sort of solution in the end.

Comment: The suggestion from @Davide works.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly your problem you could use `QuarkusTestProfile` just implements this interface and return something like this

```java
@Override
public Map<String, String> getConfigOverrides() {
        return Map.of("quarkus.lambda.handler", "name-of-the-handler");
}
```

After this annotate your test with `@TestProfile(ClassImplementingQuarkusTestProfile)` and this should be enough to let you run it.

Unfortunately after you have multiple handlers you have to set the TestProfile for all the tests.